# How to change format of "date string" in scrapy spider

Tags: php, date, scrapy

I am scraping several websites using scrapy.  One problem is that the "post_date" item has different formats on different websites, for example "06/01/2015" vs "1 June 2015".  I would like to know how to convert the date string from "06/01/2015" to "1 June 2015", which will make the date strings have the same format in MySQL.

Hypothetically, the date on the website is provided as:

```
<div class="date">06/01/2015</div>
```

The following are the parse function in scrapy spider:

```
def parse(self, response):
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
sites = hxs.select('//*')    

for site in sites:
il = ExampleItemLoader(response=response, selector=site)           
il.add_xpath('post_date', 'div[@class="date"]/text()')
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
yield il.load_item()
```

The above code successfully collect the date string as "06/01/2015".   On the other hand, when I try to convert the date string to "01 June 2015" with the following code, it didn't work.

```
il.add_xpath('post_date', 'datetime.datetime.strptime(div[@class="date"]/text(), "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%d %B %Y")')
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I got the error message as follows:

```
 exceptions.ValueError: Invalid XPath:
```

Or should I use "replace_value" to convert the format after Xpath?  Such as the hypothetical codes as follows:

```
il.add_xpath('post_date', 'div[@class="date"]/text()')
il.replace_value('post_date', 'datetime.datetime.strptime("old post_date value", "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%d %B %Y")')
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can this be done in scrapy spider?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading Scrapy documentation and testing, I came up with a solution as well as how I solved it:

```
il.add_xpath('post_date', 'div[@class="date"]/text()')
il.replace_value('post_date', datetime.datetime.strptime(il.get_collected_values('post_date')[0], "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%d %B %Y"))
```

The output I got is:

```
01 June 2015
```

Explanation: **il.get_collected_values('post_date')** is to get the collected value provided from il.add_xpath(), which is a "list" with the value of "[u'06/01/2015']".  I tried il.get_collected_values('post_date')[0] and it successfully got the "06/01/2015" out of the list.

**il.replace_value('post_date')** assigns a new value to the just collected 'post_date'.